# how can I get data from $_POST send by AJAX in symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, post

I send data in ajax like this, to my controller

```
var city='LONDON';
r.open("POST",url,true) 
r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
                   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
r.send(city);
```

this is my controller

```
public function updateDataAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();  
        $data = $request->request->get('city');

        var_dump($data);

        return new Response($data); 
}
```

when I use var_dump($data), function return me null.
How do I correctly send and retrieve the  data?

Answer (score 0):

try to print Post array using print_r($_POST); or $request->request->all();